# C++ column chart is reversed

Tags: c++

I'm stumped on why my columns are reversed. The actual column graph (asterisks only) needs to be flipped horizontally. (The population in 1900 is 2000 and the population in 2040 is 24000.)

Here is what it currently looks like:

```
Population column chart

24000  **
23000  **
22000  **    **
21000  **    **
20000  **    **
19000  **    **
18000  **    **    **
17000  **    **    **
16000  **    **    **
15000  **    **    **
14000  **    **    **    **
13000  **    **    **    **
12000  **    **    **    **
11000  **    **    **    **
10000  **    **    **    **
 9000  **    **    **    **    **
 8000  **    **    **    **    **
 7000  **    **    **    **    **
 6000  **    **    **    **    **
 5000  **    **    **    **    **    **
 4000  **    **    **    **    **    **    **
 3000  **    **    **    **    **    **    **
 2000  **    **    **    **    **    **    **    **
 1000  **    **    **    **    **    **    **    **
      1900  1920  1940  1960  1980  2000  2020  2040
```

And here's the code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int population_size = 8; //Available for changes. 
    int year = 1900;
    int population[population_size];
    bool haveFile = true;

    const string inFileName = "people.txt";
    ifstream inFile("people.txt"); //Defines input file and opens

    cout << "Population column chart" << endl;
    cout << endl;


    if (inFile){
        // cout << "Open of " << inFileName << " was successful.\n";
        int count = 0;
        while (!inFile.eof()) {
            inFile >> population[count];
            count++;
        if (inFile.eof()) break;}

        int min = 1000; //Define minimum y-axis amount
        int max = 0; //Initialize max value to 0
        for (int i=0; i<count; i++){ //Find the maximum population 
            if(population[i]> max);
            max = population[i];
        }
         //This block creates the y-axis legend and rows of stars
        for (int num = max; num >= min; num = num - 1000){ 
            cout << setw(5) << num << " ";
            for (int year_counter = 0; year_counter <= count-1; year_counter++)
                if (num <= population[year_counter])
                    cout << setw(3) << "**" << "   ";
            cout << endl;
        }
        //This block creates the x-axis legend
        cout << "    "; 
        for (int k = 1; k <= count; k++){
            cout << setw(6) << year;
            year += 20;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is in this area of code:

```
for (int year_counter = 0; year_counter <= count-1; year_counter++)
            if (num <= population[year_counter])
                cout << setw(3) << "**" << "   ";
```

population[0] should be a value of 2000, but it is 24000. Is there a problem with my array being somehow reversed?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show your data set?

Comment: 2000   4000   5000   9000   14000   18000   22000   24000

Comment: To get it compiling I also had to change population_size to a const, FYI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 if(population[i]> max);
        max = population[i];
```

should be

```
 if(population[i]> max)
        max = population[i];
```

Try that and see.

OK, I think I see what's up now.  You are trying to print populations for the various years.  Each column is essentially 6 characters wide (`"\*\*"` set in a `setw(3)`, plus a `"   "`).  Trouble is, you only print that column if it's going to get the `"**"`; otherwise you print nothing.  So all the columns with `"\*\*"` are jammed to the left.

Solution is to always print the column, for each row, whether it gets a `"**"` or not:

```
        for (int year_counter = 0; year_counter <= count - 1; year_counter++)
            if (num <= population[year_counter])
                cout << setw(3) << "**" << "   ";
            else                                    //NEW
                cout << setw(3) << "  " << "   ";   //NEW
```

Comment: Hmm, didn't seem to change anything at all

Comment: I just ran it with your data set.  I get population[0] as 2000, as you wanted.  The entire population array is `{2000 4000 5000 9000 14000 18000 22000 24000}`, just as in your data set.  Are you sure you're reading the variable right? ...and is the output wrong?  Is the 2000 supposed to correspond to 1900, 4000 to 1920, etc.?

Comment: I just altered my code with your suggestions in the main answer box above and it finally works. For some reason I didn't think I needed to account for the empty spaces, but you're 100% right. I really appreciate your help.